# JavaFX - Logarithmic Slider Tick Marks

Tags: javafx, slider, scale, logarithm

I was wondering if there is a way to make a JavaFX Slider to show logaritmically spaced tick marks. I suspect there is none. If this is the case what would be the best way to go about implementing this do you think? I should mention that I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904969/javafx-2-2-configuring-slider-ticks-manually) but the accepted answer is not what I want.

So what I know is possible is this:
[image]

But I want are tick marks spaced like this: http://www.dplot.com/logarithmic/loglin_h600.png

That the tick marks show their respective values is not important.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You would need to write a new `SliderSkin` implementation...

Comment: What is a SliderSkin?

Comment: The skin for the slider... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/skin/SliderSkin.html See also the "Architecture" section in the [`javafx.scene.control` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/package-summary.html).

Comment: Hmm okay, have never heard of that before. Will look into it!

Comment: It's a highly non-trivial task to implement a skin.

Comment: Ohh okay, I don't like the sound of that. Do you know of any good tutorials? How did you learn it? Do you maybe know of a small example somewhere I can try to wrap my head around?

Comment: Maybe just look at the source code for the skin classes from the standard library: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/10/rt/file/d14b61c6be12/modules/javafx.controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control/skin

Answer (score 1):

You can use a linear Slider with linear tick marks and every time you get a result you calculate the logarithmus of it and work with that.

Comment: This is not not what I'm asking unfortunately but thanks anyway!