# Which event for a Javafx control?

Tags: api, javafx, event-handling, fxml

While implementing an event handler for a slider in JavaFX and FXML, I was not able to figure out what event type a slider fires. I searched the Javadoc and googled it, but finally solved it by trial-and-error:  a mouse released event can track when the user has changed the value of the slider (my first guess was some kind of ValueChangeListener or ChangeListener like in swing).

Question: How can I know which event listener/handler goes with which control? If the API/Javadoc does not state that slider value changes preferably are handled by mouse events, where to look for that information?

Comment: You can listen directly to changes in the [`value` property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html#valueProperty).

Comment: In addition to the value property on slider there is also a valueChanging property which is discussed in this Q&A: [JavaFX 2.2: Hooking Slider Drag n Drop Events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892070/javafx-2-2-hooking-slider-drag-n-drop-events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX replaced most value events by Properties, since they are far more flexible. So when you wonna keep track of the current value of a component, the easiest approach is to add a ChangeListener in your case to the valueProperty of a Slider:

```
slider.valueProperty().addListener( ( ov, oldValue, newValue ) ->
{
  System.out.println( "OldValue = " + oldValue + " newValue = " + newValue );
} );
```

For a more detailed explanation with example have a look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/slider.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You may add a super class event (i.e. the most top class `Event`, and not specific event like `ActionEvent`) filter (not handler) to some parent layout (or to scene) and observe what kind concrete events are propagating through.

The other option is to simply read the source code :)

Comment: There is nothing in the source code about event type. From @crusam's answer I understand that I would rather read some document on differences between java.swing and javafx (which is a fair deal).

Comment: @crusam's answer is totally valid. There are `property`s for the node in JavaFX whcih you can add change listener or bind to other nodes' properties, but there are also events fired from node as a source to some destination node. For latter ones you can attach an event filter or handler (you may also prefer to read the difference of both).